# Is it possible to predict the arithmetic result when it's overflow already?

Tags: java

Suppose we have `int n = 2 ^ 31` then `n-1 = 0111111111111111111111111111111`, this is what I can get locally.

My guess: convert `n` to `long` first -> subtraction -> slice to fit into `int`.

```
System.out.println(n);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n-1) + " : " + Integer.bitCount(n-1));
System.out.println(n-1);


// output 

-2147483648
1111111111111111111111111111111 : 31
2147483647
```

But I found no specification to validate my guess, is there some?

From [Integer overflow wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

> When an arithmetic operation produces a result larger than the maximum above for an N-bit integer, an overflow reduces the result to modulo N-th power of 2, retaining only the least significant bits of the result and effectively causing a wrap around.

If my guess is just totally wrong, then how it actually works? Any link I can refer to?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Are you asking "does Java define the result of Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 and Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1"?

Comment: @sprinter similarly but not just `+1 or -1`. I need a `long` backup as my guess mentioned. So I don't have to introduce a `long` explicitly adding extra casting.

Comment: So you're asking "does the Java language specification define what happens when an int operation overflows"? I believe the answer is 'no'. But every jvm I've ever used treats Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry for the tag, but I am working on `java8` specifically. So I am asking version-oriented question.

Comment: @sprinter Thanks for the experience sharing, so it seems the wiki explanation still stands in my case.

Comment: Rest assured: such basic questions around ranges and exact behavior of numeric primitive types, there is really no difference here between java 5, 8, 10 or 12. All the same.

Comment: @GhostCat yeah, you should be right. But I....have no idea as to these versions...so, any way, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how arithmetic in two's complement works.

Subtracting 1 from 2^31 is the same as 2^31 plus -1, as per JLS [§15.18.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2),

> For both integer and floating-point subtraction, it is always the case
>   that `a-b` produces the same result as `a+(-b)`.

And also that

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order
>   bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large
>   two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the
>   result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two
>   operand values.

Now we can calculate the sum of 2^31 and -1 in binary. 2^31 is one 1 followed by 31 zeroes, which is -2147483648 in two's complement. -1 in two's complement is 32 ones, so we have:

```
 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
+1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

As you can see, the last bit on the left there overflows, but according to the second excerpt, we ignore that. Adding all those up, we get:

```
0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

which is 2147483647

Comment: I just checked that minutes ago but I missed that part. Thank you so much. Thank you :)